# why does mailSender always get as a null? spring/jsf

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-mail, jsf-2.2

I tried to send mail with spring in managedbean(jsf).But I get a nullpointer exception.

***MailServiceImpl.class***

```
@Service("MailService")
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService, Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Autowired
    private SimpleMailMessage alertMailMessage;

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {

        try {
            final SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

            message.setFrom(from);
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            if (mailSender != null) {
                mailSender.send(message);
            } else {
                log.info("mailSender is null." + mailSender);
            }
        } catch (final MailException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void sendAlertMail(String alert) {

        final SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage(
                alertMailMessage);
        mailMessage.setText(alert);
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);

    }

    public JavaMailSender getMailSender() {
        return mailSender;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

}
```

***\WEB-INF\application-context.xml***

```
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="host" value="smtp.mail.yahoo.com" />
    <property name="username" value="my@yahoo.com" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="alertMailMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from">
        <value>my@yahoo.com</value>
    </property>
    <property name="to">
        <value>my@yahoo.com</value>
    </property>
    <property name="subject"
        value="Alert - Exception occurred. Please investigate" />
</bean>

<bean id="MailService" class="spring.service.MailServiceImpl">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"></property>
</bean>
```

***ManagedBean.class***

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{MailService}")
MailServiceImpl mailServiceImpl;

public void sendingEmail() {
    mailServiceImpl.sendMail("my@yahoo.com", "my@yahoo.com",
            "Hi look at me!", "Bla bla bla..");
}
```

***pom.xml***

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and web.xml for application-context.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

mailSender always gets as a null.Why?How can I send an email properly?Thanks in advance.

Comment: mailSender is in a spring managed bean. How is this jsf related?

Comment: I use spring's service in jsf managedBean.So gets as a null in the JSF ManagedBean.Maybe jsf has different thing for the mailSender.

Comment: Just to clarify: which field is null, "mailSender" or "mailServiceImpl"?

Comment: Hmmmm cannot remove my upvote (by accident) on the second comment

Comment: mailSender gets as a null.I am seeing on console log.

Comment: You clarified that you are using Spring (the tag and `@Autowired` somewhere). In this case, a JSF-related annotation `@ManagedProperty`  to inject a bean/service into another bean/service will not work, since beans are managed by Spring. Besides, you are trying to inject an implementation `MailServiceImpl` and not its abstraction `MailService`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect in this case in the JSF bean you get an instance of the MailServiceImpl injected, which was created by the CDI container (or maybe JSF itself) and not Spring, so the fields in the object are null (obviously, because the CDI container doesn't know anything about Spring annotations).

If you want to inject Spring beans in a JSF managed bean, you have to put the following snippet in the faces-config class:

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>
        org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
    </el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I am already using this.and already works a lot of the injection process(dao's services for business layer) with managedproperty annotation.